# Hashing Gives Different Results for the Same Input in SQL

Tags: sql, encryption, hash, md5

I am new to Encryption. I searched a lot but could not find an answer.

When I use the below query

```
SELECT  UserName, HASHBYTES('MD5', 'trial1') [HashedPasswd] from accounts
```

I get below result as the encryption.

```
0x237103B50B9AA3496711E628FA073D6F
```

However, when I use below query where the value for the Password column is exactly trial1

```
SELECT  UserName, HASHBYTES('MD5', Password) [HashedPasswd] from accounts
```

I get

```
0x75E7A2E4F2A571D10FB8B042E4586376
```

What might be the reason for it?

Comment: Side note: Hashing is not encrypting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because "Password" is a unicode column (probably NVARCHAR) and 'trial1' is a not unicode string.

You can tell to SQL Server that 'trial1' is a unicode string by adding "N" in front of the string.

If you run this query, you will get the same hash than with the "Password" column.

```
SELECT  UserName, HASHBYTES('MD5', N'trial1') [HashedPasswd] from accounts
```